# IdP Logout Template with Ping

Tags: saml, ws-federation, pingfederate

When I use `WS-Federation` protocol and logout from my application (Service Provider) with endpoint `http://pingserver.com:Port/idp/prp.wsf?wa=wsignout1.0` , I get redirected to IdP logout template provided by Ping.

But when I use SAML protocol and logout from my application (Service Provider) with endpoint `http://pingserver.com:Port/idp/SLO.saml2?SAMLRequest=` , I get redirected to SP logout page.

I am using same IdP Adapter on Ping side, then why different behavior. Shouldn't Ping handle the last action in same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason lies in differences between the standards.

As per [WS-Federation standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/os/ws-federation-1.2-spec-os.html) (chapter 13.2.4.1), the endpoint should support parameter *wreply* with the following behavior:

> This OPTIONAL parameter specifies the URL to return to once clean-up
>   (sign-out) is complete.  If this parameter is not specified, then
>   after cleanup the GET completes by returning any realm-specific data
>   such as a string indicating cleanup is complete for the realm.

And therefore when not specified, Ping is supplying a default logout page (sourceid-wsfed-idp-signout-cleanuptemplate.html) which can be customized.

SAML 2.0 explicitly defines that in SP-initialized SLO user gets redirected back to SP with a SingleLogout message, so Ping follows that.

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out SAML side. Just needed confirmation for WS-Federation , so making sure I have implemented everything correctly for SAML protocol.